# PHP Excel read xlsx format

Tags: php, yii, phpexcel

im trying to read *.xlsx file in yii framework but have an error. `include(ZipArchive.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`  at this row `Z:\home\yii.local\www\framework\YiiBase.php(418)` I've already read *.xls file and parse them, all works good. In my `php.ini` Ive uncommented `extension=php_zip.dll` and download `php_zip.dll` but the problem still has remained. Can you give me advice, what should i do in this situation?

Here is the part of my code:

```
    include_once 'PHPExcel.php';
    include_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

    $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("region-report.xlsx");
```

im trying to add this row `include_once 'PHPExcel/Shared/ZipArchive.php';` but nothing chaged

Comment: Have you run a phpinfo() to verify that php_zip is enabled? Have you restarted your web server? Have you updated the correct php.ini file?

Comment: I rebooted my PC, and then it works:D Question can be closed.

Comment: I think you have some options to delete the question yourself. It should be deleted, not closed, because it contains nothing valuable. As you wrote above, the problem never existed, if whole solution to it is to just reboot a computer!

Comment: Or may be why cant you let it be,rather to delete it..! For whom those who dont know about it and face the same problem ??